# In what way could frost caused by weather have lead to a leaking water pump/coolant?

Tags: coolant, leak

I recently had a burnt gasket which seems to be due to no coolant\leaking water pump. For some reason I think the weather had something to do with it.  This is because the day the gasket went the was vehicle was covered in frost(which hadn't happened since i bought the vehicle). When driving on the day the water pump leaked, engine overheated, gasket went etc. My friend also had the same issue on the same day.

I read that if for example people didn't put a 50/50 water/coolant mix then when it got frosty the water may have frozen and lead to damaging the water pump, in which case i can see how the weather may have caused this.however when vehicle was serviced 2 months ago they assured me appropriate coolant mix was used.

Regardless of whatever really caused it, can you think of any other ways the weather(frosting) could have did something which may have caused the leak e.g. where an unequal mix of water-coolant is used, weather causes water to frost damaging water pump, leaking coolant.

Comment: It's a stretch to blame the weather. Your coolant would have to be very diluted in addition to it being below zero for awhile IMO. *However*, and this will seem a little nuts to some, but I do believe that any work on GMs requiring removal/replacement of the serpentine belt has a curious talent for finishing off older water pumps a few months after the repair work. I've seen it happen twice (two different cars). The only warning you'll get: it'll it seem squeaky sounding, particularly in the morning, and even more particularly on a cold morning, and then eventually it'll spring that leak.

Comment: Gaskets can maybe get dry rotted, could water from outside have got inside some how and expanded inside the gasket from the outside? This is ruling out the possibility your coolant mix wasn’t 50/50. Again don’t know if this is possible, only an idea

Comment: What do you mean by "*burnt gasket*"? How did the water pump fail (where was it leaking)? Exactly how cold did it get when there was "*frost*"?